# How to install pip for python 2.6?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I tried following the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5538353/1312080) but `easy_install-2.6` could not find `pip`:

```
>sudo easy_install-2.6 pip
Processing pip
error: Not a recognized archive type: pip
```

How do I install pip for python 2.6?

My root need for pip for 2.6 is explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294015/how-to-install-psycopg2-for-python2-6-when-there-is-also-2-7-installed).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just follow the instructions [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip):

1. Securely download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py) (this is the 2.6-specific file, link from Ricardo Iramar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353628/1426065)).
2. In the directory you saved `get-pip.py`, run

   ```
   sudo python2.6 get-pip.py
   ```

   and you'll be all set.

This will install `pip` for Python 2.6, and won't touch your version 2.7 installation.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to run with Python 2.6: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WARNING'`.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, this gives me error:  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Comment: If you don't have the super user permission, then use `--user` flag.

Comment: python2.6: command not found is the error message I get when I try this

Comment: Note that the version of get-pip.py available via this link no longer supports Python 2.6. I believe it requires 2.7 and higher. See Ricardo's answer elsewhere on this page.

Comment: I've tryed this and get this error message: ```pip._vendor.ipaddress.AddressValueError: 'XXX.XX.X.XX/XX' (len 14 != 4) is not permitted as an IPv4 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?``` (erase the current ip, but there is one where the X's are)

Comment: @MikeStoddart thanks, the link has been edited and clarified

Answer (score 35):

Find below the steps to install pip on Python 2.6.X:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

Comment: This worked, thanks, but just a note for others: current version still supports python 2.6, but future versions wont. pip command reports: *DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6*

Comment: This works better than above which was throwing an error

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for those of us still trying to support legacy systems :)

Comment: This gave me the following error: *InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this.*

Comment: Thanks for the correct link. Someone added it to my answer and I've clarified that it's the 2.6-specific one.

Comment: `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/get-pip.py` - Pradyun, on behalf of the volunteers who maintain pip.

Answer (score 6):

on fedora/centos system, just use

```
yum install python-pip
```

on other linux system,use yum-like install tool

on window ,use the other solutions under this question

Comment: Hands down the easiest solution on CentOS

Answer (score 1):

From this page : [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)

> pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and also
>   pypy.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: I do have pip installed but that works with python2.7 distro of python that is installed in parallel on my system with 2.6.  i need to get pip to work with 2.6

Comment: Ok, maybe installing from source is the right way to do it; like MattDMo suggests it.