# Iterable enum in Python 2.6

Tags: python, enums, iterable

As I am using Python 2.6 I am trying to create custom Enum class. What I need is to store string with the enum object. Something like:

```
class Enum(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value[0]
        self.msg = value[1]

class Parameters(Enum):
    SERVER_LISTEN_ADDRESS = (0, "http://blabla.com")
    SERVER_LISTEN_PORT = (1, "7001")
    SERVER_SSL_LISTEN_PORT = (2, "7002")
    (...) # many parameters more 
    SERVER_NAME = (X, "name")
```

The problem is that my 'Parameters' class is not iterable...
From another file I need to be able to iterate among PARAMs:

```
import Parameters

for param in Parameters:
    # do sth
```

Unfortunately, for my solution I have error: `for param in Parameters:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for param in Parameters:
   #
```

Above will not work because `Parameters` is class and it is not iterable.

```
class Parameters(Enum):
    PARAM1 = (0, "some msg 1")
    PARAM2 = (1, "some msg 2")
```

`PARAM1` and `PARAM2` are **class variables** in above case.

---

We have to do something like this:

```
class Enum(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value[0]
        self.msg = value[1]

class Parameters(Enum):
    def _init__(self, value):
        super.__init__(value)

PARAM1 = (0, "some msg 1")
PARAM2 = (1, "some msg 2")
for param in [PARAM1, PARAM2]:
    print Parameters(param)
```

**[Edit 1]**:

Create number of objects by for loop with range function

**code**:

```
for i in range(100):
    param = (i, "some mesg %s"%i)
    print Parameters(param)
```

**[Edit 2]**:

Get values from the User by `raw_input` function and type conversion from the string to integer

**Demo**:

```
>>> no = raw_input("Enter Number of objects you want to create(Give only number): ")
Enter Number of objects you want to create(Give only number): 33
>>> no
'33'
>>> type(no)
<type 'str'>
>>> no_int = int(no)
>>> type(no_int)
<type 'int'>
```

**Note**:

use `raw_input()` in **Python 2.x**

use `input()` in **Python 3.x**

**[Edit 3]**: Hardcode values by **Instance variables method**.

Define class in `hardcoded_values.py` file

```
class Hardcodes():
    def __init__(self,):
        self.para1 = (1, "some msg 1")
        self.para2 = (2, "some msg 2")
        self.para3 = (3, "some msg 3")
        self.para4 = (4, "some msg 4")
```

Import `Hardcodes` class in `test.py` file

```
#- Create Object(instance) 
from hardcoded_values import Hardcodes
obj = Hardcodes()
hardcode_values = obj.__dict__
for i in hardcode_values.iteritems():
    print i
```

**Output**:

```
$ python test.py 

('para3', (3, 'some msg 3'))
('para2', (2, 'some msg 2'))
('para1', (1, 'some msg 1'))
('para4', (4, 'some msg 4'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make: 'for param in [PARAM1, PARAM2]' independent from PARAMs names?

Comment: means I am not getting. `PARAM1` and `PARAM2` are variables of `tuple` types. You means you have to generate more variable like `PARAM1` ?

Comment: I mean that I can have a lot of PARAMs (f.g PARAM1 - ... - PARAM101) and I would like to be able to iterate on every PARAM without knowing its name

Comment: hmm. but in your answer you assume that there is 100 parameters. I just gave an example. It's not totally independent...

Comment: you can change this value according to your logic. e.g. we can take this file from the user by `raw_input() - Python2.x` and `input()-Python 3.x`

Comment: Many variables are in class?? means. Can you give or explain us input and output of your programme, so we can suggest you different solutions.

Comment: Vivek, I have updated my question. I don't want to generate enums, I just want to create static class with some parameters and to be able to refer to that

Comment: ok, means these values are hard coded in code and more values will add in futures . correct? 
we want to refer these values(i.e. Variables of respective values) in other py files. correct?

Comment: Exactly! In other words, I need to be able to iterate for all the params that are in Parameters class without knowing their name... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: added answer by class instance variable method

Answer (score 4):

Use the backported [`enum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)):

```
from enum import Enum


class Parameters(Enum):
    PARAM1 = (0, "some msg 1")
    PARAM2 = (1, "some msg 2")

for i in Parameters:
    print(i, '=', i.value)
```

which prints:

> Parameters.PARAM1 = (0, 'some msg 1')
>
> Parameters.PARAM2 = (1, 'some msg 2')

Comment: Hey Joschua! But I'm using Python 2.6

Comment: Hi, I think it's also available for Python 2.6. I'm curious though, why do you use Python 2.6 instead of Python 2.7. Aren't they compatible (i.e. you could replace the older version with the newer one without any ramifications)? btw. Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the environment that I'm working on :< It needs to be compatible with many machines in our network and there I have only Python 2.6. I am on Linux

Comment: It's backported down to 2.4, so this would be the best solution.

Comment: @Konrad Then you should be able to install it with `sudo pip install enum34`. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294467/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2-6)'s how to install pip if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `myo.utils.enum.Enumeration` class: https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/myo-python/blob/9335663d00df762b29e0c0f12550d8d73aa097b6/myo/utils/enum.py