# Installing pip on a windows machine python 26

Tags: python, pip, python-2.6

I'm trying to install pip on a windows machine using python 2.6.  I usually use python 2.7, but my companies production servers are running python26 so I need to  make sure my code runs on 2.6 before handing it off to them.  I'm using pip to install the following modules that my code leverages:

```
dateutil.parser
bs4
pandas
datetime
urllib2
random
os
time
os
```

I tried using the link below to install pip, but it directs me to a very long page of text and no doanload prompt. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

All of the links I've found on the topic have pointed me to the same link that doesn't seem to be functioning properly.  [How to install pip for python 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294467/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2-6)

Is there a way to install directly on the command line?  Or an alternate link I could use to install the pip module?

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: What problems are you having.

Comment: I'm not able to install pip for 2.6.

Comment: I'm moderating. Do you get an error message? Please don't expect readers to guess what you have tried and how you know it isn't working. Tx.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of specificity.  I'm a newbie.  Will edit my question

Comment: try using http://babun.github.io/ I think it comes with pip preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Download the .whl file from this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip).

Open command prompt as admin and go to the location of the file.

type the following command:

```
python.exe pip-8.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install pip-8.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.
```

Now latest version of pip should be installed.

To use pip go to your python26 folder the scripts. usually `C:\Python26\Scripts`

[EDIT]

OK this works for sure:

1. [Download](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) `get-pip.py`
2. Now just double click to open the file (or `python get-pip.py` at its location).
3. It must automatically download and install.

Make sure you have `C:\Python26` is added to your path and it did not work previously for you as you might have used `sudo` and `python2.6` instead of just `python`

Comment: I got a TypeError: NoneType object is unsubscriptable

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem and at which stage do you get that message?

Comment: I opened the command prompt as an admin and navigated to the location of the pip file (which I placed in the same filepath as where python26 is located).  I then ran the command you mentioned above and I got the  error I mentioned.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why this error has occurred.But can you place it else where and navigate accordingly, as the same python26 folder might have led to some clashes

Comment: It seems to have installed, but now when I import pip it says theres "No module named pip".  Any ideas?

Comment: So python.exe is located in C/Python26, while my scripts folder is located at C\Python26\Tools\Scripts.  SHould I move the scripts folder to be in the same directory as python.exe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109068/discussion-between-ganesh-k-and-ben).