# curl for get-pip.py does not work: Syntax Error

Tags: curl, pip, python-3.5, centos6, python-2.6

When I try to run:

```
[root@pex appliance_ui]# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io./get-pip.py | python
```

It returns:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1603k  100 1603k    0     0  7006k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13.2M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20649, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 197, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 82, in bootstrap
  File "/tmp/tmpH39pcu/pip.zip/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH39pcu/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH39pcu/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index.py", line 526
    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also,

```
[root@pex appliance_ui]# python get-pip.py --verbose
```

Output:

```
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?
I have Python 2.6 and pip 9.0.1. My aim is to upgrade to python 3.5 soon on the whole project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of Python you're using found at `python` doesn't support set comprehensions. I can see the same error trying to do `{str('foo') for c in [1,2,3]}` in Python 2.4 as opposed to 2.7 where it works.

Per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353628/3538313) and [the note in this section of the pip installation documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) you should use this URL for get-pip.py on 2.6: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py

You can also see Python 2.7 is the oldest supported version listed here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#python-and-os-compatibility

As for `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`, that's because `curl` puts the file contents on standard out, not on your file system. If you wanted to download the file you would use `wget`.

Comment: Thank you! I could get curl working, but in my virtual environment I'm unable to run `pip install requests pex` , gives me the similar error. Why would that  be happening?

Comment: No problem. @AnjanaShivangi That sounds like it could be another issue? You may have to open a separate question with the command, versions you're using or installing, and the error you're getting. It's possible that the latest versions of those packages have a `setup.py` or other code that's not compatible with Python 2.6. Please also mark the answer as accepted if it worked for your original issue :)