# How to install pip on a system with python 2.6

Tags: python, pip

A base docker image I am working with is a *relic* using *python 2.6.6* ..

So how can I install *pip* on this system - given the long obsolescence of the *python* version and the lack of availability of tools even to upgrade to newer versions.

**Update** I had already gone through *all* of the options in the other question [How to install pip for python 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294467/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2-6).

- *get-pip* link is 404  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py
- `yum install python-pip` does not work since `pip` postdates `2.6`

In general 2.6 is so out of date there are no easy answers to be found.  I am looking for someone who has an approach even with the long period since this version was obsoleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pip for python 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294467/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2-6)

Comment: I'll +1 this because it made me chuckle

Comment: I'll -1 this because it is rude and condescending... Plus it has been both asked and answered here before.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I had already gone through all of the options in that answer: the _get-pip_ link is 404, and the other options do not work

Comment: @ObsidianAge  I'm sorry you take it that way - the wording is not directed at any one person and the tone was intended as light sarcasm but not biting. You cannot tell that given the limited context .  The docker image is a relic : these things happen at big companies, but that was not intended to be a criticism of anyone.

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/ , https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/get-pip.py

Comment: @phd Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the site was changed. Pip is now under subdirectory [`pip`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/). Pip for Python 2.6 is at https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/get-pip.py