# Install pip on Python 2.6

Tags: python, pip, command-line, package, python-2.6

I need to install pip on Python 2.6. I have tried a couple of solutions available.

- *[How to install pip on a system with python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71581590/how-to-install-pip-on-a-system-with-python-2-6)*
- *[How to install pip for python 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294467/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2-6)*
- *[How to install pip with python 2.6 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560990/how-to-install-pip-with-python-2-6-on-windows)*

Commands used:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

#### Output

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1719k  100 1719k    0     0  1860k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1860k
```

#### And:

`python get-pip.py`

#### Output

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22123, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py", line 1683, in <module>
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py", line 1685, in _IPv4Constants
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py", line 1625, in __init__
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py", line 1399, in __init__
  File "c:\users\faz\appdata\local\temp\tmprxjgud\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py", line 553, in _check_packed_address
pip._vendor.ipaddress.AddressValueError: '169.254.0.0/16' (len 14 != 4) is not permitted as an IPv4 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode [sic] object?
```

Is pip still supported with Python 2.6?

Comment: Please [edit] and show text of commands that you ran after these answers and all errors and output the commands reported.

Comment: @phd alright, I edited the question.

Comment: Text output please, the image is unreadable. Complete, please. The image seems to be just a small part of sequence of commands, One command at a time, copy/paste the command and its output. Or redirect output and errors to file, copy/paste files.

Comment: @phd edited accordingly.

Comment: Much better, tnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 2.6 you need older `setuptools`. The last setuptools version that works with Python 2.6 is [36.8](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v37-0-0).

Download [setuptools-36.8.0.zip](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/04/be569e393006fa9a2c10ef72ea33133c2902baa115dd1d4279dae55c3b3b/setuptools-36.8.0.zip), unpack, `cd` into the extracted directory and run `python2.6 setup.py install` (`python.exe setup.py install` on Windows).

The last version of `pip` supporting Python 2.6 is [9.0.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31): https://pypi.org/project/pip/9.0.3/#files

Download [pip-9.0.3.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/44/e6b8056b6c8f2bfd1445cc9990f478930d8e3459e9dbf5b8e2d2922d64d3/pip-9.0.3.tar.gz), unpack, `cd` into the extracted directory and run `python2.6 setup.py install` (`python.exe setup.py install` on Windows).

I tested the process though it was hard — I failed to install Python 2.6 with `conda` or `pyenv`, no luck with Debian 6 in Docker. Finally I managed to run a VM in emulator QEMU, installed Python 2.6, `setuptools` and `pip`.

Locally the installed `pip` works but it cannot connect to PyPI because Python 2.6 is linked with ancient OpenSSL and cannot connect over HTTPS protocol to pypi.org. So for any package you need to download source or wheel distributions (including all dependencies) manually and run `pip` with option `--no-index` to disable access to PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for taking time on it and clarifying. I, however, want to check one thing still, since the pip installation went through successfully, it is still not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708898/7976758 Add its directory to `%PATH%` See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

"pip 20.3 was the last version of pip that supported Python 2. Bugs reported with pip which only occur on Python 2.7 will likely be closed as “won’t fix” issues by pip’s maintainers."

source: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/development/release-process/#supported-versions

Answer (score 0):

It says that Python 2.6 is no longer supported to the Python core team, meaning it will not be updated anymore. Try to use an upgraded version of python for the packages you want to use. If the packages you are trying to use are below Python3 or are using an unsupported version of Python, try to contact the developers of the package to upgrade it, otherwise, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.6 was released in 2008 and has since be deprecated for many years now. I think your stack trace tells you that pip doesn't support Python 2.6 because it's deprecated. This should answer your question 'Is pip still supported with python 2.6?'

Also note that the last version of pip supporting Python 2.6 is 9.0.3 hence this message in your stack trace 'No matching distribution found for pip<10'.