# Automatically Detecting and Installing Compatible Versions of `setuptools` and `pip` with PowerShell for Any Python Version

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pip, setuptools

I am trying to automate the setup of Python environments on Windows and encountered a challenge with legacy Python versions. Specifically, I need a PowerShell script that:

1. Detects the last version of `setuptools` that is compatible with the currently active local Python version, downloads it, unpacks the archive, and installs it.
2. Does the same for the latest version of `pip` that supports the active local Python version.

For context, the necessity arises from managing multiple Python environments where each might be using a different Python version, including legacy ones (e.g., Python 2.6). The script must be robust enough to automatically determine which versions of `setuptools` and `pip` are compatible with the active Python version and perform the installation process without manual intervention.

I have found [various approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77609580/4999991) for downloading and installing specific versions of packages, but I am unsure how to dynamically determine the compatible version for the current Python environment.

Has anyone tackled a similar problem, or could you provide insights into how this could be achieved using PowerShell? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** Here is how I think we can achieve a solution:

1. fetch the local version of Python using

```
$pythonVersion = python --version 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^Python\s', '' }
```

2. Define a function to query compatible package versions using the PyPI API for the package. Iterate over the releases to find the highest version number that requires a Python version less than or equal to the current Python version. for example:

```
function Get-CompatibleVersion {
    param (
        [string]$PackageName,
        [string]$PythonVersion
    )

    $url = "https://pypi.org/pypi/$PackageName/json"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url
    $releases = #parsing the JSON format

    foreach ($release in $releases) {
        $requiresPython = $response.releases.$release[0].requires_python
        if (-not $requiresPython) { continue }
        
        $isCompatible = $false
        try {
            $isCompatible = [System.Version]::Parse($PythonVersion) -le [System.Version]::Parse($requiresPython.Split(',')[0].Trim('<>=').Split(' ')[0])
        } catch {}

        if ($isCompatible) { return $release }
    }

    return $null
}
```

3. then getting the latest version of `setuptools` and `pip`:

```
$setuptoolsVersion = Get-CompatibleVersion -PackageName "setuptools" -PythonVersion $pythonVersion
$pipVersion = Get-CompatibleVersion -PackageName "pip" -PythonVersion $pythonVersion
```

Comment: How should "latest version" be defined? By the `$response.releases` NoteProperty Name string? By the `$response.releases.<Name>.upload_time`?

Comment: @lit I am a bit too novice to answer that question in a decent way, so [here](https://pypi.org/pypi/setuptools/json) is the JSON of the `setuptools` as an example.

Comment: We should look for the latest release with a `requires_python` field value equal to or lower than our local Python version and then select the one that ends with the `.zip` extension for `filename`.

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/TKbZ9TtX) here is an example of how the JSON file could be parsed to find the latest release.

Comment: @lit, I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/291169/146444).

Comment: For `pip`, there are .whl and .gz files. No .zip. Also, letters in the version names may pose an issue. What is the "latest" version in this list? `@(1.5.6, 10.0.0, 10.0.0b1, 10.0.0b2, 10.0.1)`

Comment: @lit the second one is a valid concern. Right now I am at the mercy of PowerShell to sort them inversely.